# Regex finding words which contains a given sequence and excluding a specific word

Tags: regex

I want to find words which contains a given sequence of letters. However the word should be different than a given banned word.

For instance in
"modal dalaman odal Modal ODAL amodal modalex amodale"
If the sequence is "dal" and the banned word is modal, I want to get the dalaman, odal, ODAL, amodal, modalex, amodale.

How can I do that in regex? BTW, there is no specific programming language for this question.

Comment: You could come up with [`\b\w*(?<!(?:mo))dal\w*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/rK3oP9/2) - for an explanation, please be more precise on your programming language, though.

Comment: @Jan That's basically the pattern I already suggested (with a few unnecessary additions though - you neither need the `\b` nor do you have to put the "mo" into a non-capturing group).

Comment: @ByteCommander: You're right, did not read the answer and have deleted mine.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Although I'd argue that a non capturing group will be needed to provide more alternatives (I have this strange feeling that OP has not fully posted every needs here).

Comment: @Jan My requirements did not changed. But I've added some other accepted words for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern below to match all words that contain "bar" but are not equal to "modal" as full word.

Pattern:

```
\w*dal(?<!\bmodal\b)\w*
```

Explanation:

- `\w*` matches any number of word characters (alphanumeric and underscore "_"), including zero
- `dal` matches the sequence "dal" literally
- `(?<!\bmodal\b)` is a negative lookbehind which assures that the sequence "modal" could not be matched immediately on the left of this token.
  The `\b` matches only at word boundaries, but does not consume any characters.
- `\w*` matches any number of word characters (alphanumeric and underscore "_"), including zero

[Check this regex out on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cR3dH4/1)

---

**This is the old version of my answer that was valid before the question update:**

You could use the pattern below together with the `i` (case insensitivity) flag.
Depending on what programming language or environment you use to process the regex, you might either also have to set the `g` (global) flag to match all separate occurrences of the pattern, or use a method of your environment that searches all matches, like e.g. in Python `re.findall()`.

Pattern:

```
\S*(?<!mo)dal\S*
```

Explanation:

- `\S*` matches any number of non-whitespace characters, including zero
- `(?<!mo)` is a negative lookbehind which assures that the sequence "mo" could not be matched immediately on the left of this token
- `dal` matches the sequence "dal" literally
- `\S*` matches any number of non-whitespace characters, including zero

[Check this regex out on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tO8zF4/2)

---

More general, you can use this pattern:

```
\S*(?<!%%FORBIDDEN_LEFT%%)%%REQUIRED%%(?!%%FORBIDDEN_RIGHT%%)\S*
```

after replacing the placeholders `%%REQUIRED%%`, `%%FORBIDDEN_LEFT%%` and `%%FORBIDDEN_RIGHT%%` with whatever strings you need.

For example, if you want to match "cd" but not "abcdef", you have to use the pattern `\S*(?<!ab)cd(?!ef)\S*`.

Comment: This will only match the first valid word. What about the rest?

Comment: @CinCout That depends on the language from which the OP uses the regex. In Python for example, you have a `re.findall()` method that returns all occurrences. If the language does not provide that, you would have to rely on the regex' global flag `g`. I added this to my answer for clarification. Was the downvote from you btw?

Comment: This completes the answer. I am not the downvoter though, sorry to disappoint you.

Comment: @ByteCommander I've tried your solution, with a minor difference \S*(?<![mM][oO])[dD][aA][lL]\S* for case insensitivity and with flag g. That works fine. However it also filters out words which contains the forbidden word. For instance "amodal"